# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: asked for back ref X but there are only 0 back refs

Tags: android, database, android-contentresolver

I'm doing some database work on Android, and get the following error when trying to insert a bunch of records using applyBatch.

**java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: asked for back ref 26 but there are only 0 back refs**

What's causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, it turns out that I was trying to insert a group of records using [applyBatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29), but one of the later records depended on an earlier record in the group being inserted correctly, which it wasn't (it failed).

I identified the error by doing "applyBatch" with each of the ContentOperations, one at a time. Then i could easily see why it was failing.

Note that [this post](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-contentprovideroperation-withbackreference-explained/) was helpful in figuring out the problem.